# 2D spring effects in unity

Tags: spring, unity-game-engine, animation, effects, jonas

Does anyone know how Jonas was able to achieve this effect that he talks about at 4:10 in the following video?

https://youtu.be/ZZLR-IdKtTI

I’ve tried spring joints with hinges in unity but can’t get it to work quite as nicely.

I was also wondering how they get suck a nice wobbly/underwater effect on the main character (I’m quite the beginner, so I might just be stupid)

Thanks for the help!